# How to integrate leaflet.js in ExtJs 6 as a third part component ?

Tags: javascript, html

How to integrate leaflet.js in ExtJs 6, as a third party component ?

Answer (score 0):

Ext.defind('MyComponentName',{
      extend:'Ext.panel.Panel',
      `others conf.....`,
      initComponent:function(){
         var me=this;
       me.on('boxready',{
            `initYourMap`(me.body.dom);
       })
       me.callParent();

}
})